# SVG srcset - Need to swap SVG on screen size

Tags: image, svg, responsive-design, picturefill

I have come up against a problem and I'm struggling to find the best solution.

I have a very rectangle-shaped SVG that I have 3 versions of, eg desktop/tablet/phone

Originally, I've been using the `<picture>` element with `<source>` tags and linking to the SVG. Although when done this way, on mobile chrome, the image does not retain its rectangle shape and forces it into a square. If I set a max-height, all that happens is that the svg artwork is squashed and obscured and the white space both top and bottom of the SVG remains.

However, on desktop I never got this issue.

When I use the `<svg>` tag, with an `<image>` element, all the problems go away and as long as I set a max height, it works across the board, although I'm unable to use the `<picture>` element this way, which means I cannot make use of the handy media-query attributes.

The last thing, I haven't tried yet because I do not want it to be implemented in this way would be to set the SVG as a background on a block element.

I appreciate any experienced input on this, perhaps someone with a bit more SVG cross platform knowledge than myself!

Comment: Can you please add an example that shows the issue?

Comment: Well, heres the site http://www.rosemarysmobile.co.uk/ - I decided to just show the small version of the SVG at all times (talking about the table graphic), even though I'd have liked to swap them around with picture element.

I decided to just use an inline SVG with image tag linking to the SVG. However Android stock browser has trouble rendering this, so I'll need to png fallback it.

Thanks for your time Erik, not sure there's a solution for this yet, I guess the "ideal" way around this would be to inline the SVG graphic and manipulate it's style with CSS although I'll pass for now on that.

Comment: Have you considered using media queries in the svg instead of <picture>? See e.g http://timkadlec.com/2013/04/media-queries-within-svg/.